# Insert $ in front of capture group

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have the following input text:

```
string name;
string type;
string class;
...
```

And I wish to convert them to the following:

```
string $name;
string $type;
string $class;
...
```

My attempt at regex:

```
Javascript:
"string name;".replace(/string (\w+)/,"string \$$1");
Produces (javascript console):
string $1;
string $1;
string $1;
...
Produces (regexr prompt):
string \$1;
string \$1;
string \$1;
...
```

Why doesn't inserting a backslash in front of the first $ work? What is the correct expression to achieve this?

Note: I'm using [regexr](https://regexr.com) (which runs client side javascript) to batch process my text, and the Javascript console and the  `String.prototype.replace` function in Chrome Devtools to test the behavior of consecutive $ symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A backslash in a Javascript string only has meaning when it's in an *escape sequence* - for example, `'\n'` gets translated to a literal newline, `'\\'` gets translated to a literal backslash, etc. If you have a backslash before a character that *isn't* part of an escape sequence, like `'\$'`, the backslash will just be ignored:

```js
const str = '\$';
console.log(str);
console.log(str.length);
```

Still, literal backslashes won't solve your problem. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) - to insert a literal `$` as part of the replacement string, use `$$` (the `$` is essentially an escape character here, kind of like how `\` is an escape character in string literals):

```js
console.log(
  "string name;"
    .replace(/string (\w+)/, "string $$$1")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are searching for combinations of "`string \w+`" you could use a more simple search and replace:

```
str.replace(/string /g, "string $")
```

This adds a $ after every `string` followed by a space

```js
var str = "string name;\nstring type;\nstring class;"
console.log("Original:")
console.log(str);
console.log("New:")
console.log( str.replace(/string /g, "string $") );
```